# Confused over why Ids are acting as strings rather than references

Tags: visualforce

I'm trying to traverse a relationship between the CaseComment object and the Case object to get the value of the Case's CaseNumber field.

```
<apex:outputText value="{!comment.ParentId.CaseNumber}" />
```

but I get the following error:

> Error: Unknown property 'String.CaseNumber'

So, from this I see that Salesforce is treating `ParentId` as a String rather than a reference to the Case object, as I was hoping.

I note also that the 18 character version of the ID is returned if that makes any difference.

I'd like to know:

- In what circumstances I can use a relationship such as this as a reference to another object, and in which circumstances it will merely be treated as a String?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Typically if there is a standard field that ends in "Id", you can access the reference (and thus the fields associated with that reference) by leaving off the suffix. For example, you can get the `CreatedById` value (which would be treated as an Id type in code that can be casted to a String, or simply a String if referenced via an `apex:outputText` tag), or the name of that user with `CreatedBy.Name`.

You can also use an `apex:outputField` tag on an Id (such as `Opportunity.AccountId` to display the name of an opportunity's parent account) to show the reference's `Name` field with a nifty built-in hover box (see [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1524/why-cant-i-use-a-wrapped-sobject-in-an-apexoutputfield)).

For this particular example, give this a shot:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!comment.Parent.CaseNumber}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation which is very helpful. Using the above merge expression, I am getting an error: `System.SObjectException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: CaseComment.Parent` despite the fact that the SOQL query in the contoller is in fact selecting the ParentId field for the CaseComment. In case it makes any difference, my visualforce page is for a case object but I am accessing all the CaseComments that exist for this and related cases in a pageBlockTable.

Comment: @Joe, rather than querying `ParentId`, you'll want to query the `Parent.CaseNumber` field (or perhaps both, if you need `ParentId` for something else behind the scenes). Querying just `ParentId` won't pull the fields on that associated record from the database.

Comment: OK. That's great. Thank you. I'll have to spend a bit more time absorbing this and figuring out why it works this way.

Comment: The more general case of this situation is that any lookup relationship field also has a relationship **name** that goes along with it. The field `ParentId` has the relationship name `Parent` and `AccountId` has the relationship name `Account`. For custom fields, though, the relationship name is not constructed the same way; the `__c` is removed, and replaced with `__r`. So the field `Primary_Contact__c` will have a relationship name of `Primary_Contact__r`, and the Last Name of the primary contact is `Primary_Contact__r.LastName`.